# Set UITextField at Center in UIVIew with Autolayout Programmatically

Tags: swift

I have one TextField with I have to set at center of `UIView` 
Here is the constraint

```
var dict = ["txtHome" : txtHome]
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[txtHome]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dict))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-(>=90,<=100)-[txtHome(20)]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dict))
```

But I got the Log Like,

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7966d210 V:|-(<=100)-[UITextField:0x79666440]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x796637d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7966d280 V:[UITextField:0x79666440(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7966d240 UIView:0x796637d0.bottomMargin == UITextField:0x79666440.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7966e880 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x796637d0(480)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7966d240 UIView:0x796637d0.bottomMargin == UITextField:0x79666440.bottom>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I don't understand what is trying to told help me please me out from this.

Comment: Checkout this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011395/ios-position-uiview-in-center-of-superview-using-auto-layout-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dict = ["txtHome" : txtHome]
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[txtHome]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dict))
    var verticalspace : CGFloat = (view.frame.size.height - 35) / 2
    var matrix = ["verticalspace" : verticalspace];
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-(verticalspace)-[txtHome(35)]-(verticalspace)-|", options: nil, metrics: matrix, views: dict))<br> I have already set setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)...but now i am getting my textField at Center
```

and also i have to implement this constraint at didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation() method for center while screen rotate ... :)

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the output just add
`txtHome.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)`

With absence of the constraints the view is layed out using autoresizing mask [UIView reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask), [guide](http://www.techpaa.com/2012/05/understanding-uiview-autoresizing.html)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to put the setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) repeatedly you can utilize the following extension.

```
extension UIView {
    class func autoLayoutView() -> Self {
        let theView = self()
        theView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        return theView
    }
}
```