# Center align items to the center of a uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say I have a view called `parent` which has two subviews `child1` and `child2`. My question is how can I center align the `child1` and `child2` inside parent. I know I could manually set the center values of `child1` and `child2` manually but for that Ill need to do some other calculations. My question is if there is a method that the does this for us and center aligns the items ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use auto-layout to constraint the child views' center X and/or center Y to the parent horizontally and/or vertically. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14011969/1445366) for some sample code that will help you build `NSLayoutConstraint`s appropriate to your view.

You can also use [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) to give you a more expressive syntax.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about masonry sounds interesting

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to calculate it would be to use this to manually set the x and y coordinates of the child to the parent

```
[parent addSubView:child1];
child1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(parent.frame), CGRectGetMidY(parent.frame));
```