# How to use autolayout to horizontally and vertically center an input and a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm initializing a text input and save button in my ViewController, but it's not displaying the way I want it to, as seen in the screenshot below.

I'm trying to fix this by using autolayout as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011395/ios-position-uiview-in-center-of-superview-using-auto-layout-programmatically), but it's giving me an error

> use of undeclared identifier cn

How do I properly declare an autolayout, and is this the correct way to center the `input` and `_saveButton`?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Dem Input
    input = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40)];
    input.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    input.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times-New-Roman" size:25];
    input.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [input setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
    input.placeholder=@"Type words here...";

    //The Button
    _saveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    _saveButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 18);
    [_saveButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:input];
    [self.view addSubview:_saveButton];

    cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                         toItem:nil
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                     multiplier:1
                                       constant:200];
    [self.view addConstraint:cn];

    cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                         toItem:nil
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                     multiplier:1
                                       constant:200];
    [self.view addConstraint: cn];

}
```

[image]

Comment: where did u declare cn ?

Comment: And what is `viewObj`?

Comment: @Mr.T I'm not sure how to declare cn in the header, I tried `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutAnchor *cn;` in the header, but that didn't work.

@GlennRay that was an error, meant to write self.view instead, I fixed that.

Comment: If you declared it and it was autosynthesized (i.e. you did not explicitly write `@synthesize cn`), it will be available as `_cn` not `cn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cn is **NSLayoutConstraint**

cn is used only in **viewDidLoad()** scope. So declare it in here.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSLayoutConstraint cn;

  cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:nil
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                 multiplier:1
                                   constant:200];
```