# How do I horizontally center the UIView in my UITableView section footer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm currently adding either an up or down arrow image in my `UITableView` section's footer like so:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

MoreButton *moreButton = [MoreButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 22);
moreButton.sectionIndex = section;

if (self.expandedSection == -1){
    [moreButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DownArrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
    if (self.expandedSection == section) {
        [moreButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UpArrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        [moreButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DownArrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}

[moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moreButtonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[view addSubview:moreButton];

return view;
```

This works fine, except for the fact that it has the image positioned all the way on the left, while I want it to be in the middle:

[image]

I know that this is because of the positioning I gave the frame (`CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 22);`), but I'm not sure how to set the x coordinate to have it be horizontally centered, regardless of screen size.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 22);
```

says that you want the button to appear at origin 0,0 of it's superview (the super view being the footer).

If you change it to something like:

```
moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 0, 60, 22);
```

It'll be closer to the middle.

To really do this right, you need to use auto layout.

Based on [the code from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011395/ios-position-uiview-in-center-of-superview-using-auto-layout-programmatically), you should be able to do something like:

```
MoreButton *moreButton = [MoreButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 22);
moreButton.sectionIndex = section;

[moreButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:viewObj];

NSLayoutConstraint* cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:moreButton
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:cn];

// this centers the Y... not sure if you need it or not
cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:moreButton 
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                     toItem:self.view
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                 multiplier:1.0
                                   constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:cn];
```